# JAVA Pattern Class with Special Characters

Tags: java, regex, compilation

I'm currently using this code to find any special characters in my desired string:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-z0-9 ]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(nickname);
if (m.find()) {
   // CODE
}
```

However I'd like them to be able to use the **`&`** symbol. Is there a way to not detect a specific symbol?

Comment: explain a bit with example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `&` into your regular expression to exclude it. Change

`[^a-z0-9 ]`

to

`[^a-z0-9&]`

Also, as the purpose here is to find special characters I would recommend to change regex to allow upper case characters as well, e.g. `[^a-zA-Z0-9&]`

Comment: I have made a correction regarding excluding `space` as that is not counted in special characters.